# Winforms .net 2.0: binding a textbox to a parent property

Tags: winforms, data-binding, .net-2.0

I've got a strongly typed dset, w/two datatables: Parent and Child, w/a relation linking them in the way you'd expect (e.g. parent-has-many-children).

On my Child Detail form, I show lots of info on the current child, w/binding calls like so:

```
me.txtBirthDate.DataBindings.add(New Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", MyDataset, "Child.Birthdate"))
```

But I would also like to show some info on the child's parent--say, the parent's name.  I have tried:

```
me.txtParentName.DataBindings.add(New Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", MyDataset, "Child.Parent.Name"))
```

and

```
me.txtParentName.DataBindings.add(New Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", MyDataset, "Parent.Name"))
```

But these both result in a blank text box.

I can of course put the parent properties directly on the Child DataTable & fill them w/the results of a join between the underlying db tables, but I'd like to avoid that if it's possible (my real app involves just a few Parents each w/many many Children & I'd like not to be moving so much unnecessary data).

Is that possible?

Many thanks!

-Roy

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a `BindingSource` between the `DataSet` and the controls. When using this approach, if I have controls that I want to bind to a related row from a different table, I create a new `BindingSource`, which points at the related row (his `DataSource` property is the original `BindingSource`, his `DataMember` is the parent table), and then bind the other controls to the 2nd `BindingSource`.

I usually do it all in the designer view, which just creates those `BindingSource` objects as I go along.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks much--I tried the BindingSource, but it wasn't obvious how I could use it to get at the parent.

I wound up just handling the child's CurrencyManager.CurrentChanged event, and calling .GetParentRows there.  IOW, I'm not using binding for those fields.

Thanks for taking the time!